# Existe alguma framework em php que seja semelhante as frameworks do frontend?

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Primeiro de tudo, óbvio que eu compreendo qual a diferença entre o Back End e Front end, porém minha questão é no sentido de que as frameworks de front end, vem com os seus componentes prontos, **exemplo se eu precisar de um Step Wizard, nas frameworks F.E eu simplesmente copio a estrutura do step, e linko a programação js, e está pronto**. Eu gostaria de saber se existe algo assim em php, que fosse didático dessa forma e também ao mesmo tempo que facilite a criação de sistemas e etc. (Em PHP já uso laravel, é muito bom mas a questão é referente no quesito dos componentes prontos mesmo, digamos que eu vá implementar um carrinho de compras, forms, ou um sistema de notificações, isso já viria pronto, eu apenas me daria o trabalho de fazer as conexões com o bd e etc...

Comment: Chegou a olhar o YII?

Comment: Não, darei uma olhada agora mesmo...

Comment: Muito interessante esse YII é nesse sentido mesmo que eu estava buscando, porém eu uso laravel, se eu fosse criar uma espécie de repositório próprio com componentes que geralmente são os mais usados nos sistemas, você acha que seria uma boa prática?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualquer framework php que utiliza o autoload do composer terá componentes prontos, se chama packages, existe de monte no GitHub.

Exemplos.

Carrinho de compras: https://github.com/juliobitencourt/laravel-cart

Formulários e HTML: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html

e por assim vai, existe milhares de packages prontos, quase nunca precisa-se fazer tudo do zero.

ahh esses exemplos ai foram do laravel, mas é so vc procurar generico em php que vai funcionar em qualquer framework que utiliza composer!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acredito que Laravel já é uma ótima framework de PHP! As frameworks em PHP servem para ordenar melhor o projeto (Padrão MVC por exemplo) e facilitar o processo de desenvolvimento com metodos prontos pra consulta, inserção e alteração de dados. Em PHP temos diversas frameworks, acredito que você possa dar uma estudada na documentação de cada uma delas e ver qual se adequa para sua necessidade, atualmente trabalho com CodeIgniter mas no mercado existem diversas outras como Laravel, CakePHP e etc. Mas a principal função de frameworks de php é a facilidade com métodos prontos para melhor interação com back end e melhor arquitetura do projeto (Padrão MVC)